# Compiling C++ executable for Heroku

Tags: c++, node.js, heroku, cross-compiling, child-process

I have a Nodejs server hosted on heroku and I now added a c++ function as a child process to my server.

I have read a lot of articles, and posts in this forum and this seems to be a common problem.

Everything runs fine on a local Ubuntu machine as well as MacOs. I now installed a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 16.04. for 86x64 architecture which was the architecture of my dyno when I last checked(yesterday). But now after setting everything up, compiling and deploy I get the same error, that the executable is not able to run.

So I look into the Dino OS and it has changed which leads me to the conclusion
that compiling in a VM is not practical.

I know that this is possible, but the other solutions are already up to 5 years old in this forum and I can't get them to work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

The Error Code from heroku logs:

> 2023-03-24T12:32:33.665970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13
> desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET
> path="/path/ofRouteThatRunsChildProcess"
> host=myaddress
> request_id=2a9a4b4d-c073-415d-9af2-600ee2728a6b fwd="91.17.39.75"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
> 2023-03-24T12:32:33.797308+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing any errors you get from running the executable. Very probably it is caused by missing dynamic libraries or the wrong version of glibc/libstdc++ on the Heroku side.

Comment: How could I fix it if it would fail because of this?

Comment: The "bazooka" approach is to recompile your application to only use static linking.

Comment: Unfortunately static linking doesn't solve the problem. I compiled specifically for Linux e9a7d499-70dc-49ea-9fa5-94938f40a92c 4.4.0-1104-aws #109-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 10 11:27:41 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux added static linking and changed chmod and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Then you need to figure out what  actual error is reported, first.